# Symfony2 loading big parameter variable into RAM instead of loading from disk

Tags: symfony

In a file called field_properties I store information for all the fields in my application, so that I know, depending on some characteristics (e.g. the project type, the project size) if showing a certain field or not. While I'm at it I also store the data label, so it's accessible also when I create the form.

This file has a structure similar to the following:

```
parameters:
    fieldProperty:
        entity1:
            field11:
                Label: 'Field11 label'            
                ProjectType:
                    IT: 0
                    Non-It: 1
                    Hybrid: 2
                ProjectSize:
                    Big: 1
                    Medium: 0
                    Small: 2
                Sensitivity: medium
            field12:
                Label: 'Field12 label'            
                ProjectType:
                    IT: 1
                    Non-It: 2
                    Hybrid: 0
                ProjectSize:
                    Big: 0
                    Medium: 1
                    Small: 2
                Sensitivity: medium
        entity2:
            field21:
                Label: 'Field21 label'            
                ProjectType:
                    IT: 0
                    Non-It: 1
                    Hybrid: 2
                ProjectSize:
                    Big: 1
                    Medium: 0
                    Small: 2
                Sensitivity: medium
            field22:
                Label: 'Field22 label'            
                ProjectType:
                    IT: 0
                    Non-It: 1
                    Hybrid: 2
                ProjectSize:
                    Big: 1
                    Medium: 0
                    Small: 2
                Sensitivity: medium
```

And it's quite big (there are around 2000 fields).

I assume that when I call `$fieldProperty = $this->container->getParameter('fieldProperty');` the controller access the disk to load the info. As that info practically never changes it would be better if it accessed RAM. How can I load that thing in RAM so that it's always ready to be accessed quickly?

Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.memcached.php

Comment: Seems like a nightmare to me :(. 1642563 options when all I need is to store an array into memory :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that when I call $fieldProperty = $this->container->getParameter('fieldProperty'); the controller access the disk to load the info.

Actually, yes, no, maybe, kinda :)

What happens on an initial Symfony run, it will build up a cache system that mostly are plain PHP files (files in your `app/cache` directory). In here, the (parsed) values of all your parameters files that it needs to load are stored, so the actual parameters yaml file itself will not be read and parsed from disk from that point on.

Those cache files however, will get loaded on each call you make to Symfony, but performance-wise it's better as rebuilding the container and reloading all configuration options on each call. Normally, files like these are not loaded from disk after a while, but cached by the FileSystem buffers (so it will hardly be a "real" disk seek) and/or APC/OPCache.

When you call `getParameter()`, the container will look for this parameter from the cache, making it a simple array-lookup (which are fast enough for even 2000 items).

I'd reckon the performance hit you have on 10 or 10000 items are negligible, but only benchmarks will tell you the truth.

Comment: There indeed seems to be the case! I'm not able to run a full test, but I did with a tenth of the file, which has 200 fields and generates a yml file that is 4000 lines long. I made 10000 calls of  $this->container->getParameter('fieldProperty'); and the response time was amazing. I tried to measure by dumping the microtime(true) but I'm unable to read the result. It took between "1435182954.0415" and "1435182954.0575". Are those seconds (before the . of course) so there would be a difference of 16 milliseconds?

Comment: In that case I cannot be happier, considering that I made something that is 1000 more challenging (10000 times over something that is a 1/10) than what I really need, so I can expect good performances ;). Thank you for the excellent explanation!

Comment: The difference is indeed 0.016 seconds (16 milliseconds).  This is also why it doesn't really matter if you use yaml, xml or php as configuration format (or any combination even). It will ultimately be all processed and cached into a PHP structure so only the initial caching will take (only a tiny bit) longer.